# Exporting rasterized graphics to svg does not create a single raster image in Mathematica 11

Tags: graphics, export, rasterize, svg-format

I am trying to export a rasterized density plot with vector axes and vector graphics overlayed. E.g.

```
plot1 = ListDensityPlot[list, Frame -> False, Axes -> False, PlotRangePadding -> None];
plot2=Show[
Graphics[{
Inset[Rasterize[plot1, RasterSize -> 100], {0, 0}, {Left, Bottom},Scaled[{1, 1}]]
}]];
Export["path to file.svg",plot2];
```

This has always worked in previous versions of Mathematica, however, in Mathematica 11 it now exports all pixels in the rasterized bitmap as a separate vector graphic object. As a result, the export fails unless the raster size is very small.

Here is a minimal working example

```
plot2 = Rasterize[Graphics[Disk[]], RasterSize -> 10];
Export["plot.svg", plot2];
```

When I open plot.svg in Inkscape, rather than a single Image object there is a group of 240 Path objects representing each of the pixels, and each can each be selected.